# Script based Dependent Drop-Down List not working (Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, dropdown

I have set up this script to give me a drop list on cell Y4, depending on the value chosen on cell S4. The data where both values come from are based on another sheet named DW, starting on row 2, because it has headers.

```
function onEdit(){
  var tabLists = "DW";
  var tabValidation = "EditItem";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 19 && activeCell.getRow() == 4 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){

    activeCell.offset(0, 6).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var makes = datass.getRange("A2:C").getValues();

    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()); //This gives me row2 to check below, but I need the column data, instead. How to change this one then?

    if(makeIndex != 0){

      var validationRange = datass.getRange("C2:C");
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 6).setDataValidation(validationRule);

     }  

  }

}
```

I get the list from DW("C2:C") listed on Y4, but it doesn't come "filtered", according to the item name chosen on S4.

Any light as to what I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You code so far specifies any value present in `DW("C2:C")` as a valid value for the data validation in `Y4`. If this is not what you want  -please explain better what you want.

Comment: Hello @ziganotschka!
The issue is that the items from DW("C2:C") aren't listed on Y4 depending on what's on cell S4, whose data is on DW("B2:B").

Comment: What you want to do is to check either the value of `S4` is contained in `DW("C2:C")` - and if so set `DW("C2:C")` as the permitted value range?

Comment: Correct...creating a dependent list, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If I understood your issue correctly - the problem is in your statement `if(makeIndex != 0)`

Keep in mind that the method [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` and not `0` if an entry has not been found in an array.

So, you should query for `if(makeIndex != -1)` if you want to implement your data validation only in case `activeCell.getValue()` is contained in `"C2:C"`.

### UPDATE

- You want to know which row in column `B` contains the value in `S4`
- You want to the value in column `C` of this row to be used for data validation in `Y4`

In this case you need to

- convert the entries in column `B` into a searchable array - this can be done with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- find the corresponding value in column `C` - this can be done by manually build the A1 notation of the cell with the retrieved index

Sample:

```
    var makes = datass.getRange("A2:C").getValues();    
    var searchArray=makes.map(function(e){return e[1];});                            
    var makeIndex = searchArray.indexOf(activeCell.getValue());    
    if(makeIndex != -1){
      var validationRange = datass.getRange("C" + (2+makeIndex));
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 6).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    }
```

> Notes:
>
> - It seems that you are not using column A, so there is no need to
>     include it in range `makes`
>
>   - Notaions like `A2:C` are not very efficient becasue they include many empty rows. Instead it is better to use as a margin  the [last
>       row with
>       contents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Hi!
Corrected it accordingly, but it still doesn't give the correct result and here's what I've seen:
The 2nd line of code below gives me the result to check if the Item is contained, while I actually need the column B. How to change this one then!?
var makes = datass.getRange("a2:c").getValues();                                                       
var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue());

Comment: I've edited the code, adding a comment to the line I believe the issue is.

Comment: I understand your request now. In which column do you want to look? Column A? And for building your data validation, shall any value in column C be allowed or only the cell value in the row in which `activeCell.getValue()` was found?

Comment: The activecell has a list of the items from DW("B2:B"). The datavalidation must build a list of only the cell value i the row in which activeCell.getValue() is found.

Comment: I just got a life long shortcut here, considering beginner status in coding. Thanks a million!